# FreeBSD 7.0 on Parallels, ran out of space while building ports for Mono

Tags: hard-drive, freebsd, parallels, mono-framework

**FreeBSD 7.0 on Parallels Desktop 3.0 for Mac, ran out of space while building**

I downloaded the VM of FreeBSD 7.0 here:

http://www.parallels.com/ptn/download/va/?va_id=227

and updated the ports tree and then started building Mono and dependencies.

I ran out of space on /usr/ports while building mono-2.4.2.1; that virtual hdd has 2GB. I have ~4GB free on /home. How do I (1) duplicate /usr/ports perfectly (cp -r ?) to /home/usrports, so I can move /usr/ports to /usr/old and then (2) can I just symlink /usr/ports to /home/usrports? Alternately, can I begin a new ports deal in /home/ports? I'd like to not have to start that over since I have downloaded and compiled a number of ports already, so copying would be a better option.

OR ALTERNATELY (MY REAL GOAL): What is the best route to getting FreeBSD 7.0+ (preferably 7.2) running Mono and preferably KDE (since then I can copy paste stuff via the web), on a VM in Parallels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize downloading a premade VM image is convenient, but I suggest [going to the source](http://www.freebsd.org/where.html) and installing it yourself. I suggest using only 1 partition for everything. This way you can give it a comparatively small drive (to save space on the host machine) and not worry about issues where one partition fills and another is empty.

Comment: I think I'll try this. I did it with FreeBSD 6.2 so I can get it working again on 7.2.

Comment: "comparatively small drive"... well, that was the problem, but I know what you mean. Instead of 6.5 GB with 4.5 GB free, I can just make a 6.5GB  (or 8GB) partition like my 6.2 hdd, which hasn't ran out of space with KDE and all its dependencies. If I have lots of unused free space I can try Parallels virtual hd compression.

Comment: FreeBSD 7.2 was successful. Unfortunately the binaries output by mkbundle won't run on my web host because the host web server is missing (at least one) missing .so (libm.so) file. Perhaps I can persuade them to install mono-2.4 directly.